# Nesting of groups or elements

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, entity-relationship

I'm fairly new in Mysql, but I have problem that I cannot solve. I will give you an example to demonstrate it. Please note that I know that (for current example) there are other simpler and more efficient ways to solve it... but just take it as an example of the required procedure.

- First the data: The data would be the name of a Person.

```
CREATE TABLE person(
          id INT,
          name VARCHAR(100)
        ) TYPE=innodb;
```

- Second: **Group Creation**... So this is fairly simple... and could easily done using a table '`group`' with a foreignkey to person. These groups could be arbitrary, containing any number of persons, duplicated... or not... (that is simple!!)
- Third: **MY REAL PROBLEM---** I also would like to have Groups that have other Groups as elements (instead of `persons`). This is where a really get stuck, because I know how to create a groups of `persons`, a group of `groups` (having a self-referencing foreign key)... but I don't know how to create a group that **MAY HAVE** `persons` **AND** `Groups`.

I appreciate any suggestion to solve this issue.

Thank you very much for your comments.
Regards

ACombo

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with firstly setting up the myGroup and person tables.

Secondly, I'd set up a myGroupGroup table with columns myGroupId, parentMyGroupId. This will allow you to relate group rows to child group rows i.e. "this group has these groups within it". If a group has no rows in this table then it has no child groups within it.

Thirdly, I'd set up a personGroup table with columns personId, myGroupId. This will allow you to relate person rows to a given group. If a group has no rows in this table then it has no persons within it.

```
CREATE TABLE person(
      id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
      name VARCHAR(100)
    ) ENGINE=innodb;


CREATE TABLE myGroup(
      id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
      groupName VARCHAR(100)
    ) ENGINE=innodb;

-- Holds groups within groups
CREATE TABLE myGroupGroup(
      id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
      myGroupId INT UNSIGNED,
      parentMyGroupId INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_myGroupGroup_group1` FOREIGN KEY (`parentMyGroupId`) REFERENCES `myGroup` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_myGroupGroup_group2` FOREIGN KEY (`myGroupId`) REFERENCES `myGroup` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ) ENGINE=innodb;

-- Holds persons within a group
CREATE TABLE personGroup(
      id INT,
      personId int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      myGroupId int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_personGroup_group1` FOREIGN KEY (`myGroupId`) REFERENCES `myGroup` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT `fk_personGroup_person1` FOREIGN KEY (`personId`) REFERENCES `person` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
    ) ENGINE=innodb;
```

I've tweaked your SQL a bit:

1) Replaced `TYPE` with `ENGINE`

2) Replaced table name `group` with `myGroup` (`GROUP` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html))

Good luck!

Comment: Dear Tom, Thank you for you comments and explanations. Regarding your solution, I think there is an issue (that is solved on the solution presented by ypercube): I might need that some group have BOTH person AND Group members. In any case I much appreciate your answer. Regards.

Comment: to cater for this I intended there to be a row in the personGroup table (for the persons in the group) e.g. groupId=1, personId=3 (so groupId 1 has person 3 in it). In the myGroup table a parent child relationship to indicate the groups within the group. So id=2, name='group2' and parentGroupId=1 to show that group 2 is part of group 1. You could move the self-referencing foreign key from the myGroup table into a myGroupGroup table or something similar if you wanted to make it clearer. Hope that helps!

Comment: In fact - I prefer the myGroupGroup idea (I think it is clearer). I have modified my answer accordingly. Hope it makes sense

Comment: @Tom Mac: I guess you meant to remove the `myGroup.parentGroupId` column.

Comment: @ypercube: I did, yes. Thanks - good spot (lack of sleep I'm afraid). I've changed my answer.

Comment: Your answer looks quite good. Especially if one wants to differentiate between groups of groups and groups of persons. Or, in another direction, one could even drop the `personGroup` and have a single person belong to a group only after an 1-person group is created.

Comment: Hi Tom and ypercube. I really appreciate your comments (which are of great help to me). Just let me add a few questions/comments. In your code (Tom Mac) you have create the tables person (for holding persons names) ; mygroup (to hold groups naming); personGroup (to define groups OF Persons - only); and myGroupGroup (to define Groups of Groups - only). (Please correct me if I'm wrong so far...). The problem is that I need to have groups that HAVE persons AND groups. ypercube mentioned that we could use a definition of "groups of single person". That may be the way?! Your thoughts? Regards

Comment: you are correct. Given the design above there is nothing to stop you from having a group with both groups and persons. It is just that the relationships will be stored in different tables (this is very deliberate by the way). If a group is to have both groups and persons then the same myGroupId will be present in both the myGroupGroup and personGroup tables with the respective child groups and persons. If you want a single table to hold this relationship then my solution is probably not for you. Although think carefully about mixing different types of data in one table!

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:

```
CREATE TABLE Entity
        ( EntityId INT                   --- this id could be AUTO_INCREMENT
        , PRIMARY KEY (EntityId)
        ) ENGINE = InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE Person
        ( PersonId INT                   --- but not this id
        , PersonName VARCHAR(100)
        , PRIMARY KEY (PersonId)
        , FOREIGN KEY (PersonId) 
            REFERENCES Entity(EntityId)        
        ) ENGINE = InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE Grouping
        ( GroupingId INT                 --- and neither this id
        , GroupingName VARCHAR(100)
        , PRIMARY KEY (GroupingId)
        , FOREIGN KEY (GroupingId) 
            REFERENCES Entity(EntityId)            
        ) ENGINE = InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE Belongs
        ( EntityId INT
        , GroupingID INT
        , PRIMARY KEY (EntityId, GroupingId)
        , FOREIGN KEY (EntityId) 
            REFERENCES Entity(EntityId) 
        , FOREIGN KEY (GroupingID) 
            REFERENCES Grouping(GroupingId)            
        ) ENGINE = InnoDB ;
```

Comment: Notice that this structure will allow for circular references (a group that belongs to itself or a group A that belongs to B that belongs to ... that belongs to A)